# pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The "dnspython" module must be installed to use mongodb+srv:// URIs even after pymongo and dnspython installed

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I tried to connect MongoDB using pymongo. However, I met the error of dnspython must be installed **even after I installed pymongo and dnspython.**

My code is:

```
import pymongo
USER = ''
PASSWORD = ''

client = pymongo.MongoClient(
    "mongodb+srv://" + USER + ":" + PASSWORD + "@tbn-ph9ol.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

db = client["tbn"]

collection = db["inputs"]

post = {"_id": 0,
        "temperature": 37,
        }

collection.insert_one(post)
```

**Why can not the mongodb recognize that I have installed the pymongo and dnspython?**

Comment: I suspect its a venv issue. Type `pip freeze` and report the results back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that you do not have `dnspython` installed in the environment that you are running in. If you did have dnspython installed, you will not get this error message.

This is easily proven using a scratch environment in docker; start a docker container with:

```
docker run --rm -it python:3.8.1-buster /bin/bash
```

Then at the shell run the following commands to create and run your program in a new venv with only pymongo installed:

```
cd "$(mktemp -d)"
python -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install pymongo
cat << EOF > test.py
import pymongo
USER = 'x'
PASSWORD = 'y'

client = pymongo.MongoClient(
    "mongodb+srv://" + USER + ":" + PASSWORD + "@tbn-ph9ol.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

db = client["tbn"]

collection = db["inputs"]

post = {"_id": 0,
        "temperature": 37,
        }

collection.insert_one(post)
EOF
pip freeze && python test.py
```

You should see the following output:

```
pymongo==3.10.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(
  File "/tmp/tmp.vdpqnMOnFO/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 619, in __init__
    res = uri_parser.parse_uri(
  File "/tmp/tmp.vdpqnMOnFO/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 390, in parse_uri
    raise ConfigurationError('The "dnspython" module must be '
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The "dnspython" module must be installed to use mongodb+srv:// URIs
```

You will observe the error you are getting. Now add dnspython and run again:

```
pip install dnspython
pip freeze && python test.py
```

You will now see an authentication failed message as expacted as we don't have the right username and password. You can see from the `pip freeze` command that dnspython is installed this time.

```
dnspython==1.16.0
pymongo==3.10.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    collection.insert_one(post)
  File "/tmp/tmp.vdpqnMOnFO/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 695, in insert_one
...
... <snip>
...
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to import the module:

```
import dns
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too, even after installing dnspython and pymongo.

But the error can be simply resolved by installing the 1.16.0 version of dnspython.

```py
pip install dnspython==1.16.0
pip install pymongo
```

Comment: Still stack first uninstall dnspython then reinstall using pip install dnspython==1.16.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).